# Morphisms of two fully reducible representations of a group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Consider fully reducible representations $\,A(g)\,$ and $\,A^{\,\prime}(g)\,$ of a group $\,G\,$ in vector spaces $\,\mathbb{V}\,$ and $\,{\mathbb{V}}^{\,\prime}\,$, respectively. Let them be intertwined:
 $$
 M~A(g)~=~A^{\,\prime}(g)~M~~.
 $$
 For brevity, I shall denote the kernel $\,\mbox{Ker}\,M\,$ simply as $\,$Ker, the image $\,\mbox{Im}\,M\,$ as $\,$Im$\,$. Being invariant subspaces they support subrepresentations:
 $$
 B(g)\,v~\equiv~A(g)\,v\Big{|}_{v\,\in\,\rm{Ker}}\quad,\qquad B^{\,\prime}(g)\,v^{\,\prime}~\equiv~A^{\,\prime}(g)\,v^{\,\prime}\Big{|}_{v^{\,\prime}\,\in\,\rm{Im}}\;\;.
 $$
 As $\,A\,$ is fully reducible, any of its subrepresentations has a complementary subrepresentation.
 E.g., for $\,B\,$ acting in $\,$Ker$\,$, its complementary $\,B^{\,\perp}\,$ in $\,{\mbox{Ker}}^{\perp}\,$ is
 $$
 B^{\perp}(g)\,v\,\equiv\,A(g)\,v\Big{|}_{v\,\in\,{\rm{Ker}}^{\perp}}\;\;.
 $$

It is then easy to demonstrate that the same $\,M\,$ intertwines $\,B^{\perp}\,$ and $\,B^{\,\prime}\,$,
 i.e. $\,M\,B^{\perp}\,=\,B^{\,\prime}\,M\,$. Moreover, if we postulate $\,B^{\,\prime}\,$ to be irreducible, the representations $\,B^{\perp}\,$ and $\,B^{\,\prime}\,$ become equivalent, by Schur's Lemma:
 $$
 B^{\perp}\,\simeq\,B^{\,\prime}\;\;.
 $$
 The inverse is true too: if $\,B^{\perp}\,\simeq\,B^{\,\prime}\,$, there exists a morphism $\,M\,$ intertwining $\,A\,$ and $\,A^{\,\prime}\,$.

To conclude, fully reducible representations $\,A\,$ and $\,A^{\,\prime}\,$ intertwine if and only if they have equivalent subrepresentations.
 $$
 ~~
 $$
 QUESTION 1:  $~~~$In the case of an irreducible $\,A\,$, prove that the multiplicity of $\,A\,$ in $\,A^{\,\prime}\,$ is equal to the dimensionality of the space
 $\,[A\,,\,A^{\,\prime}]\,$ of all such intertwiners $\,M\,$.
 $$
 ~~
 $$
 QUESTION 2:  $~~~$If $\,$dim$\,[A\,,\,A^{\,\prime}]\,=\,\,\infty\,$, would it be right to say that the representations $\,A\,$ and $\,A^{\,\prime}\,$ are equivalent, and their spaces are isomorphic?

Comment: For Question 1, what do you mean by the multiplicity of $A$ in $A'$ if $A$ is not irreducible? And the statement in Question 2 is false: For example, take $A$ and $A'$ to be trivial representations on a $1$-dimensional space and an infinite dimensional space respectively.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thank you for your comment. Yes, my fault: in Q1 I forgot to mention that an irreducible A was implied there. Can you please answer that question, keeping in mind that A is irreducible?

Comment: @JeremyRickard I would be especially indebted to you if you could answer Q1 using my archaic language. We physicists do not know the modern language of the evaluation map or canonical decomposition. So the naive undergraduate language would be much preferred. Thank you!!

Comment: Could you add some details to your question? What kind of group? (The question is tagged "lie-groups" but I don't think the question mentions Lie groups.) What kind of representations? (Finite dimensional or possibly infinite dimensional?) Representations over what field? (I'm guessing over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?) The answer to Q1, and even whether the claim is true, depends on some of these things.

Comment: @JeremyRickard  The field is $\mathbb{C}$. As for the group, we physicists are usually interested in things like the Lorentz group SO(1.3), the De Sitter group SO(1,4). Also the Poincare group and the Euclidean group $E_3$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard In the physics literature, people are usually dealing with finite-dimensional representations of these groups. However, sometimes infinite-dimensional representations are mentioned also. So, ideally, it would be good to know the answer to my question in both cases -- provided the answer can be formulated in a language understandable to a user (i.e to someone lacking fluency in the modern language of the pure math).

Comment: I've written out a proof. I hope it's in an understandable language: I tried to stick to terminology that you seemed to be familiar with from your question.

Comment: @JeremyRickard   Your answer to Q1, provided below, is written in a very clear manner understandable to a physicist. Clearly, you are not only a scientist but also an educator. Is my understanding correct that the statement in Q2 is, generally, wrong? Would it be possible to make some weaker statement pertinent to the case of $\,dim\,[A,A^{\,\prime}] = \infty\,$?

Comment: If $A$ and $A'$ are completely reducible representations with $\dim[A,A']=\infty$, then either there are infinitely many different irreducible representations that occur with nonzero multiplicity in both $A$ and $A'$, or there is an irreducible representation that occurs with infinite multiplicity in at least one of them and nonzero multiplicity in the other. There's certainly no reason why $A$ and $A'$ should be equivalent: in fact, one could be a representation on a finite dimensional space, and the other on an infinite dimensional space.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Good food for thought. Many thanks for this clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Question $1$, I'll assume that we're in a situation where $A$ satisfies the second part of Schur's Lemma: every map of representations $\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{V}$ is multiplication by some scalar $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. Or in the language of the question, if $N$ is such that $N~A(g)=A'(g)~N$ for all group elements $g$, then $N$ is a scalar multiple of the identity.

Suppose that $A$ has multiplicity $m$ in $A'$. So we can decompose $\mathbb{V}'$ as a direct sum
$$\mathbb{V}'=\mathbb{W}_1\oplus\dots\oplus \mathbb{W}_m\oplus \mathbb{U}$$
of invariant subspaces such that the representations on $\mathbb{W}_1,\dots,\mathbb{W}_m$ are all equivalent to $A$, and where the representation on $\mathbb{U}$ has no subrepresentation equivalent to $A$.

So there are invertible morphisms ("intertwiners") $\varphi_i:\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{W}_i$ for $i=1,\dots,m$ such that every morphism $\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{W}_i$ is a scalar multiple of $\varphi_i$. And there are no nonzero morphisms $\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{U}$.

Now define morphisms $\varphi'_i:\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{W}_1\oplus\dots\oplus \mathbb{W}_m\oplus \mathbb{U}=\mathbb{V}'$ by
$\varphi'_i(v)=(0,\dots,0,\varphi_i(v),0,\dots,0)$, where the only nonzero component is $\varphi_i(v)\in\mathbb{W}_i$.

I claim that $\varphi'_1,\dots,\varphi'_m$ form a basis of the space of all morphisms $\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{V}$, and so $m$ is the dimension of this space.

It is straightforward to check that they are linearly independent, so we just need to prove that every morphism is a linear combination of them.

Let $\theta:\mathbb{V}\to \mathbb{V}'$ be a morphism, and write 
$$\theta(v)=(\theta_1(v),\dots,\theta_m(v),\theta_U(v)).$$

Then it straightforward to check that $\theta_i:\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{W}_i$ is a morphism, and so $\theta_i=\lambda_i\varphi_i$ is a scalar multiple of $\varphi_i$. Also $\theta_U:\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{U}$ is a morphism, and is therefore zero.

So 
$$\theta=\lambda_i\varphi'_1+\dots+\lambda_m\varphi'_m$$
is a linear combination of $\varphi'_1,\dots,\varphi'_m$ as required.

Comment: Thank you for the proof. Will cogitate on it now.
As for the applicability of the second part of Schur's Lemma, I cannot help from mentioning that it is valid for finite or countable dimensions only. You may be interested in this discussion on this:
 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336559/dixmiers-lemma-as-a-generalisation-of-schurs-first-lemma/336623#336623